# Best declaration order in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, variable-declaration

I have actually a nested question :

1. Does the order of variable declaration matter in Fortran?
2. If yes, what is the best order to declare variables?

For example, is this program :

```
PROGRAM order1
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE:: array_double_2D
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: array_double_1D
INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: array_int_1D
INTEGER :: int1,int2
LOGICAL :: boolean1,boolean2
... instructions ...
```

better than this one :

```
PROGRAM order2
IMPLICIT NONE
LOGICAL :: boolean1,boolean2
INTEGER :: int1,int2
INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: array_int_1D
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE:: array_double_1D
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE:: array_double_2D
... instructions ...
```

?

(by "better", I mean efficient in memory management and faster)

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: There is one obvious case where the order of declaration is important: when another declaration depends on it in some way.  But you don't care about the "legal" aspects of the order?

Answer (score 5):

No, the order does not matter, unless your declaration depends on a previously declared entity.

Obviously

```
  integer, parameter :: arr(*) = [1,2,3]
  integer :: arr2(size(arr))
```

must use this order, because you refer to another entity.

If they don't depend on each other it does not matter. It does not matter for efficiency in any way. For style everybody can have his own opinion what is the nicest order, no reason to discuss that here.

It *could matter* in a **common block**, because then you can force an array to start at an inconvenient address in memory and be more difficult to vectorize.

It does also matter in certain type declarations:

```
  type t1
    sequence
    integer(int32) :: field1
    integer(int16) :: field2
  end type
```

will be laid out in memory differently than

```
  type t2
    sequence
    integer(int16) :: field2
    integer(int32) :: field1
  end type
```

and that one differently than

```
  type t3
    integer(int16) :: field2
    integer(int32) :: field1
  end type
```

because without `sequence` the compiler is free to insert some padding and it will typically do so in `t3`.

Interoperable types

```
   type, bind(C) :: t3
     ...
```

also enforce order of the components, but the compiler can include the padding for performance. It will use the C compiler's rules for padding.

Comment: You are right, not sure if it is in this topic, but it can be mentioned.

Comment: Please note that `sequence` types are incredibly restrictive. You cannot have the `pointer` attribute for type-components. Also, `allocatable` type-components are forbidden if you want to use the `equivalence` statement.

Comment: I know that quite well, but that is not the topic of this question and answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this....

```
PROGRAM order1
IMPLICIT NONE
!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN:     array_double_2D::64
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE:: array_double_2D
!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN:     array_double_1D::64
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(:)  ,ALLOCATABLE:: array_double_1D
!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN:        array_int_1D::64
INTEGER,DIMENSION(:)           ,ALLOCATABLE:: array_int_1D
INTEGER :: int1,int2
LOGICAL :: boolean1,boolean2
... instructions ...
```

Then there is no doubt that the arrays are on 64 byte boundaries.
There are also compiler switch options. In fort it is '-align array64byte'.
This will only make a difference if/when you vectorise, which you should want to be doing... Hence you should align the arrays/vectors somehow.